# find command doesn't work with colon in name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I copied a lot of folders containing mp3/m4a-files to my NAS-music-dir (ext3) without any problems. some foldernames contain ':' (colon), multiple dots (...) and so on. how can I use the find-command for renaming the folders by deleting colons and other unwanted characters? every simple find-command gives my an error:

```
cd /nas3/Musik
find . -type d -exec grep -H ':' '{}' \+
find: "./Eis_Am_Stiel_Volume_3:_Liebeleien--The_Shirelles": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Kicking_Television:_Live_In_Chicago--Wilco": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Respect:_A_Century_Of_Women_In_Music--Mary_Wells": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

...

the German term "Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" means "Can't find file or folder".

How can I fix that problem?
thx a lot!

Comment: `Eis_Am_Stiel_Volume_3:_Liebeleien--The_Shirelles` -- chuckle :)

Comment: You are finding directories (or `folders` as Microsoft call them) and trying to grep in them. You need to grep in **files**, so use `find .-type f ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -exec grep -H ':' '{}' \+
```

This command looks weird to me. I use the same construct a lot, but never quote the braces or escape the +. The big question though, is why you want to grep the directory.

Maybe you meant to do this instead?

```
find . -type d -name \*:\*
```

or maybe

```
find . -type d | grep ':'
```

Comment: The superfluous quoting and escaping is harmless as such.

Answer (score 1):

**Command:**

```
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*\:.*'
```

**Alternative:**

```
find . -iname "*:*"
```

**Result:**

```
./Eis_Am_Stiel_Volume_3:_Liebeleien--The_Shirelles
./Kicking_Television:_Live_In_Chicago--Wilco
./Respect:_A_Century_Of_Women_In_Music--Mary_Wells
```

**Comments:**

- When working with `find` (or any filenames being thrown around the pipeline), the practise of using ***"***<---quotes--->**"** around any identifier/variable/backreference/string will much more often than not, be helpful.
- If for some reason you do need to act on a filename sent out from `find`, using a null separator is much safer:

**Example**:

```
find . -iname "*:*" -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file ; do echo "$file" ; done
```

Will work the same as :

```
find . -iname "*:*" -print | while read -r file ; do echo "$file" ; done
```

But the first example is much safer:

- Using `-print0` causes find to output **null** separated files, as opposed to **line** separated files.  You'd be surprised where some oddly named files (especially those extracted from a download / poorly converted / otherwise) contain newline escapes which when placed non-strategically in the pipeline can be really, really bad.
- The `while IFS=` (but without a command separator), **sets** IFS for that command.  So you're not going to get any surprises if this environment var gets changed
- `while IFS= read -rd '' var`is essentially the "read" compliment to `print0` -- If you output null separators, then you also have to read null separators.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to working dir and tried all 6 versions:

*Command line scripts - version1 to version 6*

```
find . -type d -name \*:\* # V1
find . -type d | grep ':' #V2
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*\:.*' #V3
find . -iname "*:*" #V4
find . -iname "*:*" -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file ; do echo "$file" ; done #V5
find . -iname "*:*" -print | while read -r file ; do echo "$file" ; done #V6
```

*Output of V1, V2 (part)*

```
...
./Booom_2005:_The_First--E-Rotic
./Bravo:_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles
./Booom_2006:_The_First--Curse
find: "./Gold:_Greatest_Hits--Boney_M.": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
./Black_Coffee_Chapter_1:_Ambientfunk_a_Mellowmoves--Aromabar
./Beethoven:_Fate--South_German_Philharmonic_Orchestra
./Bravo:_The_Hits_2002_Part_2--Kelly_Osbourne
...
```

*Output of V3, V4, V5, V6 (part)*

```
...
./Booom_2005:_The_First--E-Rotic
./Bravo:_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles
./Booom_2006:_The_First--Curse
./Gold:_Greatest_Hits--Boney_M.
./Black_Coffee_Chapter_1:_Ambientfunk_a_Mellowmoves--Aromabar
./Beethoven:_Fate--South_German_Philharmonic_Orchestra
./Bravo:_The_Hits_2002_Part_2--Kelly_Osbourne
...
```

As you can see 1 different line in output of V1 and V2 (not so important). So let's go on with
*4 command line scripts - based on version 3, 5, 6, 1* first:

```
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*\:.*' |while read -r line; do new=$(echo "$line"|tr -d ':'); echo "$line" --- "$new";mv "$line" "$new"; done #V3
find . -iname "*:*" -print0 |while IFS= read -rd '' line ; do new=$(echo "$line"|tr -d ':'); echo "$line" --- "$new"; mv "$line" "$new" ; done #V5
find . -iname "*:*" -print |while read -r line ; do new=$(echo "$line"|tr -d ':'); echo "$line" --- "$new"; mv "$line" "$new"; done #V6
find . -type d -name \*:\*|while read -r line ; do new=$(echo "$line"|tr -d ':'); echo "$line" --- "$new"; mv "$line" "$new"; done #V1
```

*Output of V3, V5, V6, V1 (part)*

```
...
./Booom_2005:_The_First--E-Rotic --- ./Booom_2005_The_First--E-Rotic
mv: das Verschieben von »./Booom_2005:_The_First--E-Rotic“ nach »./Booom_2005_The_First--E-Rotic“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

./Bravo:_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles --- ./Bravo_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles
mv: das Verschieben von »./Bravo:_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles“ nach »./Bravo_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles/Bravo:_The_Hits_2000--Alannah_Myles“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

./Booom_2006:_The_First--Curse --- ./Booom_2006_The_First--Curse
mv: das Verschieben von »./Booom_2006:_The_First--Curse“ nach »./Booom_2006_The_First--Curse“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

./Gold:_Greatest_Hits--Boney_M. --- ./Gold_Greatest_Hits--Boney_M.
mv: Aufruf von stat für »./Gold:_Greatest_Hits--Boney_M.“ nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

./Black_Coffee_Chapter_1:_Ambientfunk_a_Mellowmoves--Aromabar --- ./Black_Coffee_Chapter_1_Ambientfunk_a_Mellowmoves--Aromabar
mv: das Verschieben von »./Black_Coffee_Chapter_1:_Ambientfunk_a_Mellowmoves--Aromabar“ nach »./Black_Coffee_Chapter_1_Ambientfunk_a_Mellowmoves--Aromabar“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

./Beethoven:_Fate--South_German_Philharmonic_Orchestra --- ./Beethoven_Fate--South_German_Philharmonic_Orchestra
mv: das Verschieben von »./Beethoven:_Fate--South_German_Philharmonic_Orchestra“ nach »./Beethoven_Fate--South_German_Philharmonic_Orchestra“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

./Bravo:_The_Hits_2002_Part_2--Kelly_Osbourne --- ./Bravo_The_Hits_2002_Part_2--Kelly_Osbourne
mv: das Verschieben von »./Bravo:_The_Hits_2002_Part_2--Kelly_Osbourne“ nach »./Bravo_The_Hits_2002_Part_2--Kelly_Osbourne“ ist nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

...
```

Then I tried a *command line script - based on version 2*

```
find . -type d | grep ':' |while IFS= read -rd '' line ; do new=$(echo "$line"|tr -d ':'); echo "$line" --- "$new"; mv "$line" "$new" ; done
```

And got *output of V2 (THIS ARE THE ONLY LINES I GOT OF ABOUT 8000 DIRECTORIES)*

```
find: "./Gold:_Greatest_Hits--Boney_M.": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Nino_Rota:_Concerto_for_Strings,_\"La_Strada\"_Suite,_Dances_from_\"Il_Gattopardo\"--Riccardo_Muti": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./38?_Festivalbar_2001_Compilation_Blu--Christina_Aguilera": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Gold:_20_Super_Hits--Boney_M.": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Who_Is_It?--Ingrid_Laubrock": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Let_It_All_Be_Music:_The_Party_Album--Boney_M.": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Who_Let_the_Cats_Out?--Mike_Stern": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./tmp2/Who_Is_It?--Ingrid_Laubrock": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./tmp2/Who_Let_the_Cats_Out?--Mike_Stern": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./tmp2/Was_Ist_Passiert?--Pur": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./tmp2/Are_You_Looking_At_Me?--Colin_Hay": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./tmp2/Are_You_Experienced?--Jimi_Hendrix_Experience": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./tmp2/Whats_Wrong_with_This_Picture?--Van_Morrison": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Was_Ist_Passiert?--Pur": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "./Whats_Wrong_with_This_Picture?--Van_Morrison": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

OK, 15 error-lines isn't a lot of errors when checking 8000 directories for ':'. But when I checked the directory names I found all of them have their original names. With other words: plenty of commands with no effect.